# Instantiate const array reference as constructor parameter using initializer list, allowed or not?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a constructor that takes a reference to an array as a parameter. Can I use a brace-enclosed initializer list to call that constructor?
Is the lifetime of the temporary array the lifetime of the constructor, or is that not guaranteed?

My main question:
**Is the following example program correct?**

```
class Test {
public:
  template <size_t N>
  Test(const int (&numbers)[N]) {
    for (const int &number : numbers)
      sum += number;
  }

  int getSum() const {
    return sum;
  }

private:
    int sum = 0;
};

int main() {
  Test test({1, 2, 3});
  assert(test.getSum() == 6);
}
```

The code above works fine, however, the reason why I'm asking this is that I'm using the same approach in a larger project, where the elements of the array are not correctly initialized.

E.g. if `{16}` is used as the argument to the constructor, sometimes the value of `numbers[0]` is `0b00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000`, which is correct, and sometimes it is a different number, e.g. `0b11111111 11111111 11111111 00010000` or `0b00000000 00000000 00000011 00010000`.
The size of an `int` is 4 bytes on the microcontroller platform I'm working on, and when `numbers[0]` is wrong, I always see the same pattern: the least significant byte is correct, but in the 3 most significant bytes, there is always a block of all ones. This leads me to believe that it was not initialized correctly.

I haven't been able to isolate the problem or reproduce it using a small example.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code if it compiles. Have you already tried enabling compiler warnings?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I'm aware of compiler bugs for initializer lists in MSVC2015

Comment: @JVApen, Yes, it compiles without warnings. I'm using `arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 5.4.1 20160919 (release) [ARM/embedded-5-branch revision 240496]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Test test({1, 2, 3});`, lifetime of the temporary array ends at `;` (so after the constructor call finished).

So your usage in constructor is correct.

But if you kept reference to that array as member, that reference would become dangling.

Comment: Okay, thank you for confirming this. I'll have to look for my bug elsewhere then.